# what's the design pattern for the sidebar navigation used by Amazon, NewEgg and LightInTheBox?

Tags: website-design, navigation, design-patterns

See the below navigation examples currently used by Amazon, LightInTheBox and NewEgg. What's the pattern called? The content containing the subcategories would slide out when the mouse is hovering over anyone of the top categories in the sidebar menu.

Any template out there that could be used to achieve the effects? Or any CSS sample available to play with?

[image: Amazon]
[image: LightInTheBox]
[image: NewEgg]

Comment: Be careful using them. Mega-menus are a major annoyance when shown immediately as it shows the mega-menu when you happen to cross its trigger area even when you were en-route somewhere else. Please use an appropriate delay on the hover. Searching for delay and mega-menu should bring up some related posts.

Comment: Amazon's mega menu is fast and usable because of some clever tricks: http://gizmodo.com/5989102/how-amazons-navigation-is-so-damn-fast & https://github.com/kamens/jQuery-menu-aim

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are called **vertical mega-menus**.

Here two articles of Jakob Nielsen about the this pattern :

> Big, 2-dimensional drop-down panels group navigation options to eliminate scrolling and use typography, icons, and tooltips to explain users' choices.

http://www.nngroup.com/articles/mega-menus-work-well/

> Big 2-D drop-downs can facilitate site navigation - if they're
>   properly designed. Two examples illustrate some mega-menu usability
>   pitfalls.

Here an exemple of a CSS framework :

http://shanejeffers.com/blog/megadrop-mega-drop-down-menu-css-framework

Comment: *Vertical* mega-menus in this case.

Comment: Yep, Vertical mega-menus to be more accurate answer.

Comment: :-) You are right guys.